# Get objects from DataBase using .sql file

Tags: sql, jdbctemplate

I've got an entity class Flower that has a long list of properties that are saved in several tables. To get the Flower objects from DataBase I'm using a very long sql statement with a lot of left joins like this:

```
public Collection<Flower> getAllFlowers() {
    String selectSql = "A VERY " + 
                       "LONG SQL "+
                       "STATEMENT WITH " + 
                       "A LOT OF " + 
                       "LEFT JOINS";

    return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(selectSql, 
                     new FlowersResultSetExtractor());
}
```

Instead, I would like to have this long statement in external .sql file. How can I achieve the save result (getting Collection of objects) using .sql?

**UPDATE:**

If I need to put some data into DataBase I use code like this:

```
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(sqlScriptFile);
    ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = 
                        new ResourceDatabasePopulator(resource);
    databasePopulator.execute(dataSource);
```

but in my case I need to read information from DB. How can I do this?

Comment: I suggest going one step further and making it a stored procedure.